# Вывести переменную по частям

Tags: php

Не работает код, который должен вывести переменную $f по частям, ошибки никакой нет, код выводит только первый символ:

```
<?php
//$a =5;
//$b = $a;
//$a = ($b = 10);
//$a = $b = 10;
//$b = $c + 10;
$a = "New , string<br/>";
$b = "\n Don't work , string";
$c = "\t Tabulate , string";
$d = "\" Name , string";
$f = "\$ Dollars , string";
echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
echo $d;
$p = true;
while(p == true) {
    for ($i = 0;$i < 8;$i =+ 1) {
        if ($f[$i] == "\$"){
            echo" Find dollar,catch it!";
        }
        echo $f[$i];
    }
    if ($f[$i] == 8) {
        $p=false;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `while(p == true) {`  пропустили $ перед p:  `while($p) {`

в цикле `for` ошибка. Вместо `$i =+ 1` должно быть `$i++`

`?>` не должно быть в конце файла, если после него конечно не идёт что-либо, к примеру HTML.

Comment: `?> не должно быть в конце файла` - его рекомендуют убирать, но это не жесткое правило. Так что **не должно** - не совсем корректно

Comment: не спорю, просто не хотелось оставлять альтернатив

Comment: Спасибо , я только начинаю , если возможно есть какие-то ещё очень грубые ошибки , подскажите пожалуйста .

Comment: Можете подсказать , какой командой можно измерять длину строки в php?

Comment: `strlen($string)` если кол-во байт, `sizeof(str_split($string))` если кол-во символов (русские буквы обычно занимают 2 байта, в отличие от англ)

Comment: оО длина строки с помощью посимвольного разбиения, вы в своем уме вообще?

Comment: не ну никто не отменял модули и `mb_strlen($string)`, но mbstring не всегда доступен... :c

Comment: да и собственно, чего вы придрались к `$i +=1`? Ошибка не в нем, а как вы указали что отсутствует `$` у `p`. Формально был нотис, а-ля `undefined constant p, assumed 'p'` или он там пишет.

Comment: не всегда доступен он был небось лет 10 назад.

Comment: так там проблема в том, что не `$i += 1`, а `$i = +1`, очепятка, вот и придрался. а в качестве замены предложил сразу ++.

Comment: @teran на самом деле там был `$i = +1`, а не `$i +=1` :)  И вообще там еще ошибка, например `if ($f[$i] == 8)` скорее всего должен быть  в цикле `for`, иначе бесконечный... да и вообще там что-то странное)

Comment: ах да, пардоньте, `+1` не заметил. но тем не менее "должно" тут тоже не хорошо выглядело.